# How show MainViewModel and hide LoginViewModel when login operation is successful

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

experts! I'm new in learning WPF and MVVM. I decided to develop some small WPF application. So I have a LoginViewModel which interacts with Database. Once the login operation is successful I need to hide the LoginView and display the MainView. I'm using the Caliburn.Micro for these purposes. But I have got a problem - I don't know how can I hide the LoginView and show the MainView. I would be appreciated if someone would help me to solve this problem :(

I've already tried to use the following actions: 
- Using the IEventAggregator _events: _events.PublishOnUIThread("message"), but no result :(
- Using the Conductor.Collection.OneActive and ActiveteItem()/DeactivateItem() methods, but still no result :(

Here is my Bootstrapper class:

```
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        private SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();

        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();

            ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<PasswordBox>(
            PasswordBoxHelper.BoundPasswordProperty,
            "Password",
            "PasswordChanged");
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            _container.Instance(_container);
            _container
                .Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>()
                .Singleton<IApiHelper, ApiHelper>()
                .Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>()
                .Singleton<ILoggedInUserModel, LoggedInUserModel>();

            GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(type => type.IsClass)
                .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(viewModelType => _container.RegisterPerRequest(
                    viewModelType, viewModelType.ToString(), viewModelType));
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
        }

        protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
        {
            return _container.GetInstance(service, key);
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
        {
            return _container.GetAllInstances(service);
        }

        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            _container.BuildUp(instance);
        }
    }
```

Also here is my LoginViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
    {
        private IWindowManager _windowManager;
        private IApiHelper _apiHelper;
        private ILoggedInUserModel _user;
        private IEventAggregator _events;

        private string _login = "test";
        private string _password = "test";
        private bool _isAdmin;

        public ShellViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager, IApiHelper apiHelper, ILoggedInUserModel user, IEventAggregator events)
        {
            _windowManager = windowManager;
            _apiHelper = apiHelper;
            _user = user;
            _events = events;
        }

        public string Login
        {
            get { return _login; }
            set 
            { 
                _login = value; 
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Login);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanPerformLogin);
            }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return _password; }
            set 
            { 
                _password = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Password);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanPerformLogin);
            }
        }

        public bool IsAdmin
        {
            get { return _isAdmin; }
            set
            { 
                _isAdmin = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsAdmin);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanPerformLogin);
            }
        }

        public bool CanPerformLogin
        {
            get
            {
                bool output = false;
                if (Login?.Length > 0 && Password?.Length > 0)
                {
                    output = true;
                }
                return output;
            }
        }

        public ShellViewModel(IApiHelper apiHelper, IWindowManager windowManager)
        {
            _windowManager = windowManager;
            _apiHelper = apiHelper;
        }

        public void OpenSignUpView()
        {
            _windowManager.ShowWindow(new SignUpViewModel());
        }

        public async Task PerformLogin()
        {
           //Here I need to hide my LoginView and show the ShellView
        }

        public void CloseForm()
        {
            TryClose();
        }
```

And here is my ShellViewModel:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Screen, IHandle<LogOnEvent>
    {
        private IWindowManager _windowManager;
        private IApiHelper _apiHelper;
        private ILoggedInUserModel _user;
        private IEventAggregator _events;

        public SelectYourTreeViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager, IApiHelper apiHelper, ILoggedInUserModel user, IEventAggregator events)
        {
            _windowManager = windowManager;
            _apiHelper = apiHelper;
            _user = user;
            _events = events;
            _events.Subscribe(this);
        }

        public void Handle(LogOnEvent message) //Here I've tried to use events to show/or hide view
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Some text!");
        }
```

Comment: Maybe this can help https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition , to me it seems that ShellViewModel should inherit from Conductor, while LoginViewModel should inherit from Screen

Comment: You can also check if reply to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/58625046/49077 can help

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show the structure of the WindowManager class. ? You can open a window in WPF like this:

```
new LoginView().Show();
```

And so close it again.

```
myAlreadyOpenedLoginView.Close().
```

Here LoginView must be a window and inherit from the class Window.

Comment: Jamez Fatout. Thank you for your reply. I use a standard IWindowManager interface, which is being provided by Calliburn Micro out of the box. So that's why, there are no Close and Show methods in my VievModels. For displaying the LoginView I use following code: IWindowManager.Show(new LoginViewModel()); But there is a problem - I need close my LoginView and open ShellViewModel in case the login is successful automatically. But I don't know how can I do that, using Calliburn Micro.

Comment: I dont hear from Calibrun Micro. You can use the WPF .net logic.